# How to have a copy of sent email on sent items folder

Tags: delphi, smtp, send, indy10

I send emails with Indy 10 components on Delphi XE6. It work fine but I would like to have an copy of email on my sent items box. On SMTP server, like Gmail it work automaticly, but on MS Exchange the email not sent on sent items box.

Is it an option on Indy or it's functionnality of SMTP server ?

Comment: That's something done by the mail server, and/or possibly your mail client. it's not the smtp protocol's job to do that. smtp is purely about mail delivery. how that mail is stored on the sending/receiving end has nothing to do with smtp.

Answer (score 2):

SMTP has no concept of a "Sent items" mailbox.  IMAP has a concept of that, but it does not have any sending capabilities.  *Some* SMTP servers *may* automatically save a copy of the sent email, but that is not a requirement of the SMTP protocol.  Usually, after you have sent an email using SMTP, you have to then login to IMAP and manually save a copy of the sent email into the "Sent items" mailbox.

Comment: I have the same issue and reached the same conclusion. It would be nice thatTidSMTP could have an "imap" part to implement this "copy to imap sent folder" easily

Comment: IMAP is a whole different (and quite complex) protocol.  Putting IMAP capabilities into `TIdSMTP` makes no sense. You can use `TIdIMAP4` for the IMAP portion.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own mail address as CC recipient. The sent mail will not appear in the `Sent items` folder but in the Inbox. SMTP does not offer a better solution.

Comment: Yes, I know, and more efficient, you can add mail address as CCI.